# Can the IndoorAtlas ios SDK run in the background without the ios operating system kill it?

Tags: ios, iphone, indoor-positioning-system

I'm looking for a solution for the following developing problem:

We are developing an ios (on iPhone, ios 8) application, based on the indoor positioning system, and we have found the IndoorAtlas geomagnetic solution. It is very good, but I don't know, how to solve that keeping running the IndoorAtlas in the background, if the user exit from the app or put the app in the background?
Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in normal application. Only certain type of applications can execute code in background, and even those are only woken up for the related callbacks of the application type.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

In your case, the location background mode could work.